# Removing or preserving unmatched quotes in Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, csv

We're currently reading in a client's tab-delimited file row by row and using Dataweave to handle the transforming of the data to models for persisting to the database.

The issue we're having is that single double-quotes are causing problems with the mapping to the models.

Is there a way to handle unmatched double-quotes in Dataweave? We have a short term option of removing the offending quotes or removing all quotes entirely.

The other, preferred option is to preserve the data as is, single double-quotes and all, so the database data matches the original source data.

Can I achieve either of these results in Dataweave alone?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please post input and desired output sample.

Comment: As an example, if we have <tab>"unmatched<tab>extra the result would be along the lines of "unmatched/textra in a single column, where what is wanted is "unmatched in one column, and extra, in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmatched double quote will cause issue, if possible you can changed it to `\"unmatched` so that it can passes as it is to downstream. Other options which you mentioned will alter the source data. Use of escape character prevent data alteration.

Comment: Thanks anupambhusari, I've ended up putting a pipe character infront of all double quotes and added it as an escape character                <dw:reader-property name="escape" value="|"/> and this is preserving the data as is.